# How can I fetch images from below response using Retrofit 1.9?

Tags: android, retrofit

I couldn't fetch image url and set in imageview. How can I fetch images from below response using Retrofit 1.9?
JSON Response is below:

```
{
"url": [
    "http://demo.in/url1/image/707/20170315063426.jpg",
    "http://demo.in/url2/image/707/374728.jpg"
],
"imagelist": [
    {
        "imageId": "1",
        "slipId": "707",
        "agentId": "6",
        "imageType": null,
        "slipImage": "20170315063426.jpg"
    },
    {
        "imageId": "2",
        "slipId": "707",
        "agentId": "6",
        "imageType": null,
        "slipImage": "374728.jpg"
    }
],
"slipId": "707",
"agentId": "6",
"message": "",
"success": "1"
}
```

My code is below For fetching response from JSON and I dont know how to get List of image url and set in ImageView:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyRecyclerView task_list;
MyAdapter mAdapter;
public static List<String> taskEmployeeLists;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    task_list=(MyRecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.task_list);


    task_list.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    task_list.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    getListofTask();


}

private void getListofTask() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("please wait....");
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("username","vishal" );
    map.put("password", "vishal");
    map.put("slipno", "707");

    ApiHandler.getApiService().signin(map, new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Example feedcomment, Response response) {
            try {
                if (feedcomment.getSuccess().equals("1")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    taskEmployeeLists = feedcomment.getUrl();
                    Log.e("Commentlistsize", taskEmployeeLists.size() + "");
                    try {
                        mAdapter = new MyAdapter((ArrayList<String>) feedcomment.getUrl());
                        task_list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("exception", e.toString());
                    }
                } else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.e("status", "0");

                    task_list.setAdapter(null);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("comment exception", e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("retrofit_error", error.toString());
        }
    });
}

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;


    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> url) {
        mDataset = url;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public View mainView;
        ImageView task_detail,task_discussion;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mainView = v;

            task_detail = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.task_detail);
        }
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_tasks_data, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mDataset.get(position).getUrl().toString()).noFade().into(holder.task_detail);
    }
    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: use `glide` or `picaaso` libs

Comment: I want to know about how to fetch "url" array from response and set in recyclerview using retrofit

Comment: for details tutorials of Retrofit  follow this links https://futurestud.io/tutorials/tag/retrofit

Comment: Can u send me code for this?

Comment: SO is not code writing website next time post your code as well what you have tried. follow this tutorial  
 http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Here is an example how to parse your json with Gson. You have to create Pojos matching your json and annotate the fields with `@SerializedName("fieldname")`

Here is what your Pojos should look like (I removed getters and setters). Demo:

```
public class Example {
    @SerializedName("url")
    private List<String> mUrls;

    @SerializedName("imagelist")
    private List<Imagelist> mImagelist;

    @SerializedName("slipId")
    private String mSlipId;

    @SerializedName("agentId")
    private String mAgentId;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String mMessage;

    @SerializedName("success")
    private String mSuccess;
}
```

And your Imagelist Pojo:

```
public class Imagelist {

    @SerializedName("imageId")
    private String mImageId;

    @SerializedName("slipId")
    private String mSlipId;

    @SerializedName("agentId")
    private String mAgentId;

    @SerializedName("imageType")
    private Object mImageType; // Fill in correct type - String maybe?

    @SerializedName("slipImage")
    private String mSlipImage;
}
```

When building your Retrofit interface you have to add a GsonConverterfactory:

```
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

Your Retrofit Interface should have a method like

```
@GET("your/path")
Example requestImageList();
```

You can't pass an url into an ImageView directly. I would recommend you to use an Image Processing library for this job and not use Retrofit directly. Examples are [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Here is an example for Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(example.getImageList().get(0))
    .into(imageView);
```

Here is an example for Glide:

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .load(example.getImageList().get(0))
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I know about set image url in imageview. I want to know about how to fetch "url" array from response and set in recyclerview using retrofit

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your implementation might slightly differ but they main concept should apply.

Comment: @dipdipdip use `Parcelable` instead of  `Serialize`. because Serialize is a slow process. This method create a lot of temporary objects and cause quite a bit of garbage collection

Comment: Yes good point. But keep in mind that you have to provide the Parcelable implementation. Afaik this isn't relevant for Gson itself but only if you want to pass data around in your Application. The Annotation `@SerializedName` for Gson still remains the same nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all you will have to parse the above response. Retrofit does this with Gson, 

new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.SERVER_URL)
                .client(client)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGSonClient()))
                .build();


And get that response as a Model, from that model you can use the image URL
```

Comment: can u send me code for how to get jsonarray of "url"?

Comment: https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/recyclerview-json-parsing.html  this site best explains the parsing and implementation of Retrofit

Comment: I have no key value JSONArray before url .How to get url List from model class?

Comment: @VishalVaishnav your posted json is clearly seems that its in json key value pair

Comment: Here you will get an array of url :

private List<String> url = null;

public List<String> getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(List<String> url) {
this.url = url;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can look at a number of online tools available that convert your json to POJO.

1. http://www.freecodeformat.com/json2pojo.php
2. http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com